# Where can I find files uploaded by users in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I'm a Joomla forum admin. I want to delete users' uploaded files. Where can I find files uploaded  by users in Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the component used but by default files will go to the images folder which is in the root folder of the site.
You can see them from the Admin panel by going to "Content -> Media"